# How to do polynomial division with integer coefficients

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials

I am looking for a method that given two polynomials with integer coefficients gives me the remainder of the first polynoial divided by the second. Note that in my case it can never happen that fractions appear anywhere during the division, for the purpose I need it its all integers! I tried using `numpy.polydiv` for this but it returns the coefficients of the remainder polynomial as `class 'numpy.float64'`. Converting back to int gives a lot of inaccuracies.

Does numpy not support what I am looking for or is there another package that would be better suited for that.

Comment: So you are saying the true answer is an integer coefficient polynomial, but numpy.polydiv gives float answers that are so wrong that rounding them to integers gives the wrong answer? Could you give an example of this happening? I'm not able to reproduce.

Comment: @mCoding It only starts happening for polynomials with fairly big coefficients. For example I tried dividing (x+3)^31 by x^29-1.

Comment: The result should be x^2+3 (mod 31), but numpy.polydiv gives me something different